# Matlab white noise signal with a maximum frequency

Tags: matlab, fft

I need to generate a white noise signal with Matlab that has a maximum frequency of 5, 10 and 20 Hz. I know one way is to create the signal, then do a fourier transform, adjust the signal frequency and then inverse transform the signal back to the time domain. I can't really figure out how to do that in Matlab. Any help at all would be great

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at online resources? Which ones? What about those resources did you not understand?

Comment: Generate an additive white Gaussian noise signal with `randn`, then put this through a low-pass filter with bandwidths / cutoff frequencies to be 5, 10 or 20 Hz.  You can certainly do it in time-domain, but frequency domain is probably more efficient.  However, if you're looking for a frequency domain approach, check out this post from MathWorks: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/71959-how-to-generate-white-noise-of-particular-frequency-in-matlab#comment_143278

Comment: As it also says in the post of *rayryeng*: *White noise cannot be of a particular frequency*, so technically after the transform we can't call it white noise anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to generate a white noise signal with Matlab that has a maximum frequency of 5, 10 and 20 Hz.

That's the same as saying "I need a perfect circle, but it has to have exactly three edges". White noise doesn't have maximum frequencies; it's white because it spans all your bandwidth with the same expected noise energy.

Now, I presume you want to say "I want to have noise that is shaped a bit like signals that center around 5, 10 and 20 Hz". You'd still have to define the spectral shape -- but for the sake of argument, I assume you want to have gaussian shaped frequency response around these frequencies with a bandwidth of 2 Hz, with a sampling frequency of 50 Hz (has to be twice the highest frequency your signal has[in the real signal case], or else you'll get aliasing).

You can simply do that by using matlabs filter design toolbox, and applying the resulting filter to your signal. Usually, you'd just design one filter and shift it in frequency, but that doesn't seem to be your level of expertise yet -- which indicates that experimenting is an extremely good approach to becoming accustomed to DSP. *Go wild!*